# Adding a digit in php

Tags: php

I have 2 values, one for accessing in and one for accessing out in a job. I want the difference between both time.

I have this code:

```
$totalworkhours = $hoursout - $hoursin;
        if($minsin > $minsout){
            $totalworkhours--;
            $totalworkmins = 60 - ($minsin - $minsout);
        }else{
            $totalworkmins = $minsout - $minsin;
        }

        echo "Total Work TIME: '$totalworkhours:$totalworkmins'<br>";
```

however i noticed that let's say if the minsout > minsin i'll go to else (8:43-3:48), i'll get 7:5.. How can fix it so ill get 7:05

Comment: try str_pad() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function.
So it would be

```
echo "Total Work TIME: '$totalworkhours:" . str_pad($totalworkmins, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . "'<br>";
```

Comment: Please consider adding some information on how to use this function in order to properly help the OP out with his specific problem.

Comment: but how to specify to str-pad() that if there is one digit add 0?

in the case 7:48-3:33 i'll get 15 min
so i need it when the result is one digit such as 48-43=5

Comment: It will pad it to specified length. If there are 2 digits, it won't touch it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has built in features to do that.

There you go :

```
$in = new DateTime('2015-07-21 10:50:00');
$out = new DateTime('2015-07-21 12:45:00');
$interval = $in->diff($out);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Using a function to wrap all this :

```
function shiftDuration($in, $out)
{
    $inDate = new DateTime($in);
    $outDate = new DateTime($out);
    $interval = $inDate->diff($outDate);
    return $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
}

$duration = shiftDuration('2015-07-21 10:50:00', '2015-07-21 12:45:00')
echo "Total Work TIME: $duration"
```

More information about PHP DateTime can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)